# Where can a user ask a question about their behavior on a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Asking about one's own activity on a Stack Exchange site violates this principle.

> ### Make it relevant to others
>
> We like to help as many people at a time as we can. Make it clear how
>   your question is relevant to more people than just you, and more of us
>   will be interested in your question and willing to look into it.

But I still think it's useful and reasonable if a user can ask for advice about their behavior.

For example, asking a question on xxx.meta.stackexchange.com:

1. What's your advice about **all** of my xxx.stackexchange.com answers?
2. What can userid:xxx do to improve the quality of their answer**s**?
3. What's your best advice to userid:xxx on the xxx subsite?

here I use `userid:xxx` to avoid repeating question title, and If you use this title `What's your advice about my stackexchange account?`, what about the others? I don't mean I am going to discuss other users.

Does anyone ask those questions in a chatroom?
If there's nowhere to do it, do you think we should open a new site for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think the bar for "make it relevant" is as high as you think. Asking about your own activities is fine on Meta.

For example, on Meta.SO, users will fairly frequently ask for help with their [specific question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specific-question) or [specific answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specific-answer). Questions about how suggested edit or other reviews should be handled are also common.

Meta sites overall are quite good at extrapolating general ideas from a specific item, or applying existing general guidelines to give advice about a particular situation. That's pretty much what they're for. Later, the discussion about your specifics may be used as an example for someone else's.

So asking for advice about your own stuff is fine. The other two of your examples deserve a mention, though: asking about *another* user in specific is not a good practice. There is a principle against calling someone else to the carpet. Pointing a finger at another user in public, no matter what they have done, is rude at best and at worst can cause some undesirable mob activity.

If you have a question about someone else's behavior, **anonymize it** and discuss it as a **case study**, not as a public trial. If the behavior is problematic, point it out to moderators via a flag and let them handle it privately.

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, it's alright to ask these questions on the site's own meta. Focus on the **underlying problem** you're having, such as not being able to find the right references, having trouble to convince the author of the question that your solution is helpful, etc., and illustrate those with example posts; definitely not the other way around.

Other users who might be having the same kind of problems will benefit from the advice the site regulars will be able to give you; in this way, you're creating a relevant Q&A which is a valuable addition to the Meta site.

By the way, a sentence like "What can userid:xxx do to improve the quality of their answers?" gives me the impression you're asking the question for *somebody else*. If that really happens, try to anonymize the user and focus on the *content* of the posts.